# How can I Delete File Which It's in Use by Read Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to delete a folder after a POST request but i can't because it's in use by a read stream. I tried `.destroy();` and `.unpipe();` but it's still in use. I can't delete files until i close my nodejs app. How can i release it ?

I declare my read stream variable globally so i can destroy and unpipe it out of scope.

```
var file;
```

Here my Read Stream Function :

```
app.get('/api/video/:folder' , function(req, res) {
  var streamer = req.params.folder
  const path = 'D:/Clips/' + folder + '/clip.mp4'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  const range = req.headers.range

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1]
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1

    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    //const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }

    res.writeHead(206, head)
    file.pipe(res)
  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
});
```

and here is my delete request :

```
app.post('/api/delete', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
  file.unpipe();
  file.destroy();
  var delFolder = req.body.folder;
  fsextra.removeSync('D:/Clips/' + delFolder);
});
```

It's giving me error because the file is in use by read stream.

How can i end read stream process ?

Comment: `file` would need to be a more complex data structure that can track all streams for all folders that might be currently running.

Comment: @matt This will stream to just one person at the same time. There is no multiple users. So i just want to flush all readstreams for delete the file. I tried soo much alternative but still no luck.

Comment: You might not have a reference to all readstreams though. All it takes is a timeout or refresh somewhere and you could have multiple streams open for one client but only one that can be closed. That could be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait for the `close` or `error` event before trying to delete the file.

```
var delFolder = req.body.folder; // sanitise this

const deleteRespond = () => {
   return fsextra.remove('D:/Clips/' + delFolder)
      .then(() => res.json({ deleted: true }))
      .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: error }))
}

if (!file || file.closed) return deleteRespond()
file.on('close', deleteRespond)
file.on('error', deleteRespond) // for `destroy`
file.unpipe()
file.destroy()
```

It's hard to test as deleting open files works fine on unix systems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's giving me syntax error. So i add closed paranthesis after `.then` and `.catch` and syntax issue solved. But when i try to use it's giving me error. Here output from console :
http://prntscr.com/iv1yqp

Comment: When i changed `fsextra.remove` to `fsextra.removeSync` then it's giving me same error with my original code. `...directory not empry, rmdir...` so file still in use. I need another `createReadStream` after `else` on my function. I think i should `.unpipe()` and `.destroy()` it too. I tried it with my code but i failed. I couldn't make it fit with your example code.